# Detecting a user leaving my website

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, socket.io

I've been using `beforeunload` to check my users leaving web pages, and it all works well, the thing is, now I want to run a function **only** when the user is leaving my website / domain.

So for example, going from `mywebsite.com` to `mywebsite.com/app` wouldn't trigger the function, but going from `mywebsite.com` to `google.com` would.

I don't care about what website they're going to, I just want to know if they're staying on my domain or not.

I can't get anything on the parameter of the `beforeunload` function. I've read a bit around the web, but no cigar. Any ideas?

Comment: I think you can't do this. It sounds like privacy-loss for the users to me, to know where are they going to go from your own website.

Comment: I don't care about what website they're going to, I just want to know if they're staying on my domain or not.

Comment: @FábioSantos that's not possible. You can only see the previous page from the new one, not the other way around. One solution would be to place a listener on every `a` element in your HTML and check what its target domain is, and act appropriately when clicked - but that's not nice at all.